# Why does pointer typecasting to float doesn't work?

Tags: c

Hi everyone I am learning C and i am trying to print values of different data types using a single char pointer. I am able to print almost every data type but having problems to print float. Can anyone explain why this is an issue ?! And how can i print the exact float value using a single pointer. Sorry for the noob question, if it turns out to be one. I understand the alignment problem. But really need a solution to this.

UPDATE 1--> Sorry for the stupid typecasting. Now consider the update code.

UPDATE 2 --> Thank you everyone for answering. Like i said,i am learning C, sorry for the syntax errors. I am not from CS background.But thank you so much again.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long int a = 10;
    char ch = 'a';
    float b = 16.89;
    unsigned int c = 20;
    short int d = 30;
    char *p;
    p = &a;
    printf("Value of a: %d\n", *p);
    p = &ch;    
    printf("Value of ch: %c\n", *p);
    p = &b;                                     
    printf("Value of b(float): %f\n", *p);
    printf("Value of b(decimal): %d\n", (int) *((float*)p));    
    p = &c;
    printf("Value of c: %u\n", *p);
    p = &d;
    printf("Value of d: %i\n", *p);
    return 0;
}

The output of the above program is :-
Value of a: 10
Value of ch: a
Value of b(float): 0.000000
Value of b(decimal): 16
Value of c: 20
Value of d: 30
```

Comment: @david, I do understand alignment issues. But there must be a work around for this right? I want to understand that !

Comment: The type casts you do in this sample program do not make any sense. F.e. `p = (long int*)&a;`. The type of `a` is `long int` and this makes the type of `&a` to be `long int *`. The type cast in front of `&a` is a no-op.

Comment: You're not typecasting anything for the print of 0.000000!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think you're confusing something here... there is no strict aliasing violation

Comment: Do not change the question using the suggestions you get in the answers. This renders the answers incorrect. Change only your actual code.

Comment: `(float*)p = &b;` is an error, the code should fail to compile. The left-hand operand of `=` should be an lvalue, but the result of a cast is not an lvalue

Comment: Now your code is again invalid - all of the `p = &a;` still need a cast to `char *`!

Comment: @Gahlot you're supposed to *compile* your program before you submit it.

Comment: @antii yes i do get warnings. What's the right way?

Comment: @anti i did compile it, it is compiled, i just get warnigs.

Comment: "just" get warnings? It is a dangerous mindset, that a warning is not worth fixing. You should strive for a clean compile - warnings are there for a reason. Basically, treat warnings as errors which the compiler thinks it is smart enough to fix, but would prefer you do it in case it botches the job.

Comment: The latest edit is still full of errors, `&a` may not be assigned to `p`

Comment: @M.M I only get warnings from the above code. If you still feel there are any errors please tell me what are they and how to solve them.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of works by accident. `p` is a char pointer; so `*p` is always a char.

- You take the address of `a`, converting it into a `long int *`. It already was a `long int *`, because you took an address of a `long int` - so this doesn't really do anything. Then you stuff it into `p`, which is a `char *`. It cannot remain a `long int *` while in a `char *` variable; it's now a `char *`. Now, you are apparently on a machine that uses [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) architecture, like the majority of us, so the least byte comes first: your `long int a` is represented as `[10, 0, 0, 0]`, and `*p` reads the first byte. Then another idiosyncracy of C comes into play: all integral parameters smaller than `int` are passed as `int`; so the byte `10` gets converted into an `int` and pushed to the stack (or handed through an integer register in newer architectures' ABI), which is then correctly read off by `printf` using `%d` format, expecting an `int`.
- For `char ch`, `*p` doesn't read the *first* byte, it reads the *only* byte; and the rest is all the same. Ditto for the rest of integral types, where you were kind enough never to go over <strike>255</strike> 127 [thanks, Antti Haapala!] (or you'd see an unexpected result).
- However, `float b` is a different story. Floats are represented in memory in a very different way than integers; when `*p` reads the first byte, it gets something quite unrelated to `16.89` - kind of like trying to guess a painting while looking through a kaleidoscope. The first byte gets expanded to int and passed to the function. In an older architecture, it would then get read as if it were float, but in [current ABIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions), where up to four (MS) or six (UNIX) integral and float parameters get passed through registers, it doesn't even get looked at (since it gets passed through an integral register, but `%f` will look at a float register). Remember, this is mostly because your pointer ends up as a `char *`, because of the way you store it.
- In `decimal(b)`, you do something very different: you cast the pointer *where it matters*. So here, the value of `p` gets to be a `float *` for a bit; then you dereference it, and correctly get `16.89`; then you convert that to an `int`, and end up with `16` (which you print with `%d`, so all is fine).

tl;dr: Type of C variables is set in stone. Any casts you do only matter while you're not storing them - as soon as you put them in a variable, the type is the variable's type.

Comment: Over 127 most probably!

Comment: Also there is no stack being used here, otherwise the result would not be 0.00000!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: How is there no stack being used? Doesn't `printf("Value of a: %d\n", *p)` do `push p; push addressof("Value of a: %d\n"); call printf`? If not, I'm missing something important in my C head-model...

Comment: actually, it *can* result in 0.00000 print here too on stack. But the point is that the floating point values are passed in *registers* on 64-bit architectures, so none of this "stack" stuff applies.

Comment: I checked all int values from -128 to 127 and then copied their representation over the beginning of a *double* with memcpy and all resulted in 0.00000 printout :D so it can be either/or.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `16.89` is `0x41871eb8` - so I figure what got passed was `0xb8`, expanded to `int` as `0x000000b8`, which is `2.58E-43` when read as `float`... which indeed prints as `0.000000` using `"%f"`.

Comment: Yes, but if I use any floating point calculations prior to that line in the program, it prints the result.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Sorry, don't know what you mean, what calculations, where? You would have to show the code to be clear.

Comment: `printf("%f\n", 42 / 31.2); printf("Value of b(float): %f\n", *p);`  => `1.346154
Value of b(float): 1.346154`, hence the stack explanation is not going to lead very far.

Comment: The reason is that the values are not passed on stack but in registers on x86-64. Hence my pointing out that explaining things with stack can go wrong, so it is better to not mention stack at all :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala No, I got that point - but I still don't understand how a subsequent `printf` prints the value of the preceding `printf`'s argument. `*p` is passed, but `42/31.2` is printed, even though `*p` is not `42/31.2`. Looks like a bug, TBH, but it can't be because it's GCC and GCC people are way smarter than me :P

Comment: `%f` prints the value of a SSE register. `*p` is passed in an integer register.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Changed; please see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The type casts you do in this sample program do not make any sense.

F.e. `p = (long int*)&a;`: the type of `a` is `long int` and this makes the type of `&a` to be `long int *`.
The type cast in front of `&a` is a no-op.

The type of `p` is `char *` and this makes the type of `*p` to be `char`. A `char` value is stored on 1 byte. Use values larger than `256` in your program for `a`, `c` and `d` and you'll discover that it prints incorrect values for them.

The value you pass to `printf()` must match the format specifier you use, otherwise you get unexpected results. Passing an integer (`*p`) and formatting it using `%f` does not magically do any type conversion, it just forces `printf()` interpret the sequence of bits of `*p` in an incorrect way and produce unexpected results because it is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

The typecasts you are doing here

```
p = (float*)&b;
```

is in implicit cast and is not required. Already, `&b` is of type `float*` and does not need a cast.

You actually need a cast in the `printf` statement. Like this..

```
printf("Value of b(float): %f\n", *(float*)p);
```

You need similar casts in all other `printf` statements too.

What you are doing here is of not much use, if you want to print an `int` use an `int` pointer, not a `char` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

it should have worked had the typecast during `printf` is correct

```
printf("Value of b(float): %f\n", *(float *)p);
```

the `float` types do not represent in a similar as that of any other integral data types essentially they essentially follow [floating point standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

now `printf` in your code expects a `%f` on the other hand `*p` is of type char, already an *undefined behavior* is induced in here